# Decode protobuf without schema in C#

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, protobuf.js

I am having the below protobuf text and would like to deserialize in C#. I have tried the below code but it keep throwing error **'Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: System.Object**. I know I require a schema is there a way turn the protobuf text data into string or Json. I am using Marc Gavell library protobuf-net.

```
public void DeserializeProtobuf()
{
    var path = $"../../protobufSingleEntry.txt";              
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    Serializer.Deserialize<object>(stream);
}
```

**protobufSingleEntry.txt**

```
00000000: 7e6d 7e37 357e 6d7e 0829 1247 0a0f 7173  ~m~75~m~.).G..qs
00000001: 5f67 554d 4463 7556 514e 6837 3912 0f42  _gUMDcuVQNh79..B
00000002: 494e 414e 4345 3a42 5443 5553 4454 1a02  INANCE:BTCUSDT..
00000003: 6f6b 293d 0ad7 a3b0 7cc6 4035 0ad7 73c3  ok)=....|.@5..s.
00000004: 3de1 7a04 c051 5c05 31d0 037d cc40 9a01  =.z..Q\.1..}.@..
00000005: 027b 7d7e 6d7e 3735 7e6d 7e08 2912 470a  .{}~m~75~m~.).G.
00000006: 0f71 735f 4e7a 784f 7a4a 4d79 4277 6b6b  .qs_NzxOzJMyBwkk
00000007: 120f 4249 4e41 4e43 453a 4254 4355 5344  ..BINANCE:BTCUSD
00000008: 541a 026f 6b29 3d0a d7a3 b07c c640 350a  T..ok)=....|.@5.
00000009: d773 c33d e17a 04c0 515c 0531 d003 7dcc  .s.=.z..Q\.1..}.
0000000a: 409a 0102 7b7d                           @...{}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is: protobuf is an ambiguous format. The same bytes could mean very different things depending on the information only known in the schema. For example, raw binary (`bytes`) payloads, text strings, sub-messages, and "packed" primitive values **all share the exact same markings**. Likewise, for most primitive types there are multiple ways of representing the same *value*, and yet also all the primitive types overlap in how they are encoded.

It is certainly possible to decode the data *abstractly* without schema - everything can be treated as an unknown field, and you can query unknown fields via an API. But that still doesn't help you actually interpret the data, because again: you need to know *what you're expecting* to apply the correct decoding.

IMO your best bet here is to actually *reverse engineer the schema*. You could start with https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode to show what the actual payload contains, and start piecing it together from there.

Comment: I do have the decode but it's in JavaScript. https://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/xyrc0w4d/